# How to ignore anchor if button is clicked within the anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, anchor

I have a situation where clicking on an image will direct the user to a certain link, but pressing a button that is shown within an image will run a javascript method instead. However, I cannot prevent the page from redirecting to the certain link when the button is pressed (the javascript method is also run when the button is clicked).

I have found out that button cannot be nested within an anchor element, and tried to wrap the button within a form as well, but no luck.

Does anyone know a way around such problem?

the basic logic in code looks like this

```
<a href="an item description link">
    <img src="an item image"/>
    <form style="display: inline" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <button type="button" id="add-btn" class="add-cart" onclick="quick_add()">+</button>
    </form>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's completely invalid to put interactive elements inside an `<a>` tag. The first thing you should do is rework your markup so that it's not nonsense.

Comment: @Pointy which method would be the best then? I am trying to make something like this work https://www.goodeggs.com/sfbay/seasonal-produce-new

Comment: if they ask for a zipcode in the link, 94104 works!

Comment: WTF!!! How you could use an anchor as a wrapper for a form, and with a button inside!!! This is insane. Please read about writing HTML semantic, or HTML for beginners. **http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way that validates would be just superimposing the button over the link. This requires the link and the button to be in the same containing element, and for both of them to use `position: absolute`:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="http://example.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </a>
  <button>AAAAA</button>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.box > a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box > button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

See it in action on CodePen: http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/avYLjQ

The button will automatically be stacked over the preceding link. (This is specified behaviour.) And it will handle clicks before they can be passed to elements underneath is.

That said, this solution has a few downsides. You'll have to give a fixed size to the container; it can't be sized automatically to fit its contents, because its contents are outside of the rendering flow. This also means they won't automatically fill their parent box unless you set their size explicitly again.